# Show + or - percentage value for the total displayed

Tags: jquery, json

I want to achieve the percentage value for the total shown. here is the fiddle

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/binoymat/d9f8t9vj/11/`
```

This is my complete code for HTML

```
<select id="category"></select>
<select id="category1"></select>
<select id="category2"></select>
<select id="category3"></select>
<br>
<br>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-2 " id="services_block" style="width: 230px;height:100px; background-color: orange;color: white; line-height: 30px; text-align: center; font-size: 100%;  font-weight: bold; border-left:3px solid white; >
Visitors <br> CURRENT DAY<br>
<span id="totalVisitorsCurrentDay" style="color: black; font-size: 150%;  font-weight: bold;" > </span>
</div>
<br>


<div class="col-sm-2" id="services_block" style="width: 180px;height: 100px;  background-color: red;color: white;line-height: 30px; text-align: center; font-size: 100%;  font-weight: bold; border-left:3px solid white;>
Visitors  
<br> PAST DAY
<br>
    <span id="totalVisitorsPastDay" style="color: black; font-size: 150%;  font-weight: bold;"></span>
    </div>
<br>

<div class="col-sm-2" id="services_block" style="width: 180px;height: 100px;  background-color: red;color: white;line-height: 30px; text-align: center; font-size: 100%;  font-weight: bold; border-left:3px solid white;
border-right:3px solid white;">Visitors 
<br> PAST WEEK
<br>
 <span id="totalVisitorsPastWeek" style="color: black; font-size: 150%;  font-weight: bold;"></span>
  </div>
  </div>
  <br>
```

Complete Jquery code

```
$.getJSON("https://api.myjson.com/bins/2soxd", function (data) {
//code inside
var items = data;
var checkIds = [];
$.each(items, function (k, v) {
    if ($.inArray(v.id, checkIds) == -1) {
        $("#category").append('<option value="' + v.id + '" data-price="' + v.visitors + '">' + v.chains + '</option>');
        checkIds.push(v.id);
    }
});

$("#category").on('change', function () {
    var dept_number = parseInt($(this).val());
    var price = $(this).find(':selected').data('price');
    var tochange = false;
    var total = 0;
    var totalVisCurrDay= 0;
    var totalVisPasDay= 0;
    var totalVisPasWeek= 0;
    $.each(items, function (k, v) {
        if (v.id == dept_number) {
            if (tochange == true) {
                $("#category1").append('<option value="' + v.id + '" data-visitorscurrday="' + v.visitorscurrday + '" data-visitorspastday="' + v.visitorspastday + '" data-visitorspastweek="' + v.visitorspastweek + '" data-price="' + v.visitors + '">' + v.site + '</option>');
                $("#category2").append('<option value="' + v.id + '" data-visitorscurrday="' + v.visitorscurrday + '" data-visitorspastday="' + v.visitorspastday + '" data-visitorspastweek="' + v.visitorspastweek + '" data-price="' + v.visitors + '">' + v.zone + '</option>');
                $("#category3").append('<option value="' + v.id + '" data-visitorscurrday="' + v.visitorscurrday + '" data-visitorspastday="' + v.visitorspastday + '" data-visitorspastweek="' + v.visitorspastweek + '" data-price="' + v.visitors + '">' + v.date + '</option>');
            } else {
                $("#category1").html('<option value="' + v.id + '" data-visitorscurrday="' + v.visitorscurrday + '" data-visitorspastday="' + v.visitorspastday + '" data-visitorspastweek="' + v.visitorspastweek + '" data-price="' + v.visitors + '">' + v.site + '</option>');
                $("#category2").html('<option value="' + v.id + '" data-visitorscurrday="' + v.visitorscurrday + '" data-visitorspastday="' + v.visitorspastday + '" data-visitorspastweek="' + v.visitorspastweek + '" data-price="' + v.visitors + '">' + v.zone + '</option>');
                $("#category3").html('<option value="' + v.id + '" data-visitorscurrday="' + v.visitorscurrday + '" data-visitorspastday="' + v.visitorspastday + '" data-visitorspastweek="' + v.visitorspastweek + '" data-price="' + v.visitors + '">' + v.date + '</option>');
                tochange = true;
            }
            total += v.visitors;
            totalVisCurrDay += v.visitorscurrday;
            totalVisPasDay += v.visitorspastday;
            totalVisPasWeek += v.visitorspastweek;
        }
    });
    $('#dept-input').val(dept_number);
    $('#price-input').val(total);
    $("#totalVisitors").text(total);
    $("#totalVisitorsCurrentDay").text(totalVisCurrDay);
    $("#totalVisitorsPastDay").text(totalVisPasDay);
    $("#totalVisitorsPastWeek").text(totalVisPasWeek);
}).change();

$("select[id^='category']:not(#category)").on('change', function () {
    var dept_number = parseInt($(this).val());
    var price = $(this).find(':selected').data('price');
   var VisitorsCurrentDay = $(this).find(':selected').data('visitorscurrday');
  var VisitorsPastDay = $(this).find(':selected').data('visitorspastday');
  var VisitorsPastWeek = $(this).find(':selected').data('visitorspastweek');
    $('#dept-input').val(dept_number);
    $('#price-input').val(price);
    $("#totalVisitors").text(price);
   $("#totalVisitorsCurrentDay").text(VisitorsCurrentDay);
    $("#totalVisitorsPastDay").text(VisitorsPastDay);
    $("#totalVisitorsPastWeek").text(VisitorsPastWeek);
});
});
```

> for eg:- when the page is loaded... if the total value **(shown in orange)** is greater than the total value shown in the yellow boxes, then i want to display the percentage value that is achieved from dividing it. If its negative.. then i want to show the negative symbol(-) along with the percentage

here is the screenshot of the output I want to achieve.

[image]

Pls edit my fiddle for any solutions

Comment: You should always add relevant code here at SO

Comment: hi, my code is added in the fiddle

Comment: Please add your code to the question. A fiddle is a great addition, but if the link becomes unavailable your question cannot be answered and will be useless to future visitors. This is why the warning you tried to get around exists.

Comment: And as stated by @Satpal add that code to the question itself. Click [edit] and press `Ctrl + M`.

Comment: Are you asking the logic to calculate %?

Comment: alrite:-) thank u for the information.. will edit it rite away

Comment: yes... for the logic and executing it practically on the fiddle i posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
  $("#totalVisitorsCurrentDay").text(totalVisCurrDay);
    $("#totalVisitorsPastDay").text(totalVisPasDay+" / "+(100-(totalVisPasDay*100/totalVisCurrDay)).toFixed(2)+"%");
    $("#totalVisitorsPastWeek").text(totalVisPasWeek+" / "+(100-(totalVisPasWeek*100/totalVisCurrDay)).toFixed(2)+"%");
```

js:http://jsfiddle.net/as9k7uda/

Comment: thank u.. u perfectly placed the value inside the div.. makes work more easy... same approach how to do it for other drop-downs???

Comment: wrap the content in a div and style that div

Comment: like `html('<div style="font-size: 150%;">'+totalVisPasWeek+"</br>"+(100-(totalVisPasWeek*100/totalVisCurrDay)).toFixed(2)+'%</div>');`

Comment: then move the beginning of the div to enclose only the %

Comment: `html(totalVisPasWeek+'</br><div style="font-size: 150%;">'+ (100-(totalVisPasWeek*100/totalVisCurrDay)).toF‌​ixed(2)+'%</div>');`

Answer (score 0):

Check this. Change the value 
http://jsfiddle.net/d9f8t9vj/13/ and you will see the %

```
var percent = (100 - (VisitorsPastDay * 100) / VisitorsCurrentDay);
```

Comment: works well from the second, third and fourth drop-down...  but not for first drop-down